# Permissions on redirect to subsite

Tags: permissions, redirect

I have a MOSS 2007 site and a couple different subsites. I want to set up the subsites so that, if you don't have access, you can request it. If you *do* already have access, you go right to the subsite.

On the Home site, I have a link in the left-hand NavBar. When they click the link they should go to the subsite if they already have access. If they don't, they fill out a short survey (with name, phone, etc) so that we can grant them access. After that, we can drop them back at the 'home' page.

How can I set this up? If your answer is JavaScript (or some other type of code), please include it or tell me where I can get it.

**EDIT:** I don't have access to the web.config or any back-end settings. I'm an admin for a site that is part of a much larger group of sites.

Comment: More or less, This kind of functionality is available out-of-box. If a user don't have access, he can click on request access link on access denied page. A site admin will get email about it and then grant permissions.

Comment: Well, we want something a little more 'elegant' than that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically with only your set of rights and your possibilities you havent got enought rights, permissions to implement a good solution to what you want.

Basically for the best approach you will have to develop for example with httpmodule and have full access to SharePoint Object Model, but in your case you don't have any.

So I hesitate that you can solve this. As you will not know what kind of permissions user have, can he enter the site or not, or if you wait for a SharePoint to decline the access to the website it will be already too late to catch it with JavaScript...

So you should think about something else ....

Hope i could set you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a custom registration page(to fill name,phone etc) and redirect users on it via httpmodule.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ketaanhs/archive/2009/03/16/moss-sharepoint-2007-custom-error-page-and-access-denied-page.aspx

If you implement this solution, please be aware that "Sign in as different user" functionality will not work (It uses default access denied page). So if you are ok with that,Go with this solution.

You can also modify the MOSS access denied page but the change will be applied to all web applications on the server.

Comment: Oops. I guess I forgot to mention... I only have remote access to the Sharepoint site. I can't change the web.config file. I administer my own site which is part of a much larger system. The back-end admin part is done elsewhere.

Comment: So basically you can not develop anything in a back-end .... httpmodule in this case will not be a solution